# How to prevent SQL injection in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-4

In my controller I have this code:

```
public function create($brand_id)
{
    Brand::findOrFail($brand_id);
}
```

and this:

```
public function search() 
{
    $q = Input::get('q');
    $brands = Brand::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$q.'%')->take(80)->get();
```

Is this code safe? By "safe" I mean SQL injection safe. Or should I do some variable clean up here? And what is the best way for cleaning up user input?
Thanks a lot for helping me :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

yes Eloquent uses parameter binding behind the scene, which safely escapes any input used in where().

Comment: I tested this myself... I don't think this is correct

Comment: @OkiemuteOmuta Well if it is not safe can you provide an example? because documentation states: Note: The Laravel query builder uses PDO parameter binding throughout to protect your application against SQL injection attacks. There is no need to clean strings being passed as bindings.

Comment: Exacly, Laravel provides protection for injection out of box if you are using either Eloquent or query builder. It is quite interesting why you think it is not correct.

Comment: But it doesn't protect you when using raw statements withing a query builder.

Answer (score 6):

Document says that Eloquent handles this behind the scene but you can also use like  `DB::escape($q)` to be in safer side

Comment: If it says it does, and the code evidently proves that it does, then wouldn't this be unecessary overhead? You will already be on the safer side.

Comment: We can use it in case of stored-procedures with dynamic parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Yes but note not all parameters are safe in the where statement:

```
public function search() 
{
  $col = Input::get('col');
  $brands = Brand::where($col, 'LIKE', '%sql injection in column name%')->take(80)->get();
```

In this case sql injection is possible!

The first parameter: the column name is not validated or checked and sql injection is possible here, make sure you protect this properly yourself!