# Auth::attempt () in Laravel 5.5 always return false

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-authentication

I use Hash to bcrypt password in my seeder, and in my controller, I use Auth to check request from client, but it always returns false, I don't know why.

This is the code:

My HomeController:

```
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $username = $request->input('username');
        $password = $request->input('password');

        if( Auth::attempt(['mssv' =>$username, 'pass' =>$password])) {
                $success = new MessageBag(['successlogin' => 'welcome']);
                return view('welcome')->withErrors($success);
            } else {
                $errors = new MessageBag(['errorlogin' => 'Login fail']);
                return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($errors);
            }
        }
    }
```

My seeder has:

```
    DB::table('sinhvien')->insert([
        'hoten' => 'Nguyễn Ngọc Anh Thư',
        'mssv' =>'DH51400668',
        'pass' =>Hash::make('DH51400668'),
        'created_at'=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        'updated_at'=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
    ]);
```

My model User:

```
    <?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

    class User extends Authenticatable
    {
        use Notifiable;

        /**
         * The attributes that are mass assignable.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $table='sinhvien' ;
        protected $fillable = [
            'mssv', 'hoten', 'pass',
        ];

        /**
         * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $hidden = [
            'pass', 'remember_token',
        ];
    }
```

and my router has:

```
Route::post('/login', 'HomeController@login');
```

but when I request with info of seeder, `Auth::attempt ()` always return false.

Comment: Is there any reason for surrounding username and password with additional quotes within the strings?

Comment: i do not understand your question @NicoHaase

Comment: change `if( Auth::attempt(['mssv' => '\''.$username.'\'', 'pass' =>'\''.$password.'\'']))` to `if( Auth::attempt(['mssv' => $username, 'pass' =>$password]))` as there is no need of surrounding username and password with additional quotes as said by NicoHaase

Comment: i think it is negligence in my code, but when i change it as your comment, it aslo return same result

Comment: did you run the seeder using `php artisan db:seed` ?

Comment: yeah, i ran it  before

Comment: try running specifying class `php artisan db:seed --class=UsersTableSeederClass` and make sure there is data in database

Comment: i checked in my database and I am sure it is in my database

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47811285/3348994

Comment: It seems like it is not related to my question

Comment: you added error which is shown in the link i shared. show actual error what you are getting.you have edited your question 2 times which can confuse anyone. please be sure that whatever you are showing is actual and is running(and still causing error).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `Hash::make` from password capture field.  When you use `Auth::attempt` it will get hash value by default and search through DB.

Try

```
$password = $request->input('password'); # remove Hash::make

if( Auth::attempt(['mssv' =>$username, 'pass' => $password])) { # remove quotes
```

---

[How to prevent SQL injection in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978439/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-laravel)

Comment: i think it is negligence in my code, but when i change it as your comment, it aslo return same result , i dont know why

Comment: No way. I gave you a working example. Create a user with the app and try to log. works fine